# Can User turn off Background Task in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

In Windows Phone 7.5 there is a way to turn a backgroundagent by going to Settings->Applications->background tasks

Is there a similar thing in Windows 8 for me turn it off?

This is a programming question because I want to get an answer to this for me to use this following API in my application. If user turns it off then I need to go for 'Push notification' implementation on my server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: @mydogisbox I have edited my question give more clarity. This is a question about an API usage, and whether I have a consequence of end user turn it off if I use this. Do you still think it is not appropriate here?

Comment: Ah, ok.  So you what to know if you need to account for the ability to turn off background tasks.  I'm pretty sure they can't turn it off in Windows 8, but they might be able to in WP8.

Answer (score 3):

If you are building background tasks that are tied to the lock screen, they can be disabled.  See the Settings - Change PC Settings - Personalize

AFAIK, other background tasks like background audio, file transfer, maintenance, etc. cannot be disabled by the user.  Not a background task expert, so possibly I missed something, but pretty sure I have it right.

[image]